# Rails - Hex value showing instead of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `devices` table which is related to a `pops` table (Point of Presence).

In my `Device` CRUD application I can show the entry for a particular device, e.g.:

```
<p>
    <label for="d_description">Description</label><br/>
    <%= text_field 'd', 'description'  %>
</p>

<p><label for="d_pop_id">Pop ID</label><br/>
   <%= text_field 'd', 'pop_id'  %>
</p>
```

where `d` is the object of the selected device but I don't want to show the actual foreign key `id` from the database, I want to show the relevant name from the `pops` table:

```
<p>
    <label for="d_pop_id">PoP</label><br />
    <%= collection_select 'd', 'pop_id', @pops, :id, :name, {:include_blank => "Select PoP..."}, {:selected => @d.pop_id} %>
</p>
```

This gives me some odd looking hex string in the `selected` attribute:

```
<select id="d_pop_id" name="d[pop_id]" selected="#&lt;Pop:0x1114a7330&gt;"><option value="">Select PoP...</option>
```

So, I tried printing out the `pop.id` and it does the same thing:

```
<p>pop id: <%= @d.pop_id %></p>
```

I've also tried using `.to_s` on it but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

The output of this is

```
<p>pop id: #<pop:0x1114a7330></pop:0x1114a7330></p>
```

but if I do the same with any other property from the table then it displays correctly.

I'm sure I had something similar crop up yesterday but it seemed to be down to the way the relationships were defined between the two classes. Just for completeness I'll add it to the question:

**device.rb**

```
belongs_to :pop_id, :class_name => "Pop", :foreign_key => "pop_id"
```

**pop.rb**

```
has_many :devices, :foreign_key => "pop_id"
```

Comment: In the `device.rb` definition you declared to have an object-to-object relation to the class Pop stored in the `pop_id` field. I think you can try to rename it to be just `pop`, so in the `pop_id` field you will have a corresponding pop id.

Comment: What @KamilBednarz said. Why name the relationship `pop_id`, it's confusing. `pop_id` is the foreign key column in the table and should be that. I think you're confusing ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that was the convention, e.g. `belongs_to :foreign_key_column, :class_name => "Foreign Key Class", :foreign_key => "foreign_key_column"` but I think I've understood it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<p>pop id: <%= @d.pop_id.id %></p>
```

In your device model,

```
belongs_to :pop_id, :class_name => "Pop", :foreign_key => "pop_id"
```

So upon `@d.pop_id` will fetch the related record from the pops table for the device `@d`.
But the naming of your association is little different, if you can use following in your Device mode, it will look better. Its just a suggestion only.

```
belongs_to :pop #you no need to define the class_name and foreign_key explicitly. By default rails take care of these.
```

and in your view, you can access it

```
@d.pop.id
```

Comment: that displays it correctly on it's own but I'm not sure why. Also updated the select but the markup is `selected="3"` whereas I expected the appropriate option to be selected :|

Comment: ah, that's perfect. Thank you so much for your help, I thought I was following convention with the relationship definition but looks like I got my wires crossed somewhere.